# Squiggly lines on display, logic board failure or display issue?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, logicboard

I have not seen such lines before. I'm not sure if it’s logic board or display problem. Can someone identify by looking at the picture?

[image]

Comment: Most likely a display issue (did you put something heavy on top of your laptop while it was closed?), time to visit a service center.

Comment: It almost looks like zalgo or glitch text - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YIxm.png - Take a screenshot & look at it on a different device. If the screenshot is clean, then it's the display that's cracked. If it's the same, then it's something in software.

Comment: No nothing heavy and there is no exterior sign of damage on the laptop. Do you think replacing LCD display will fix this issue? some display issues come from logic board i am not able to telll which if logic board is ok. Service centers often charge the price of laptop itself for repair :D since the laptop is a bit old, I wanted to do a DIY fix. @nohillside

Comment: Do the test Tetsujin proposed. If it is an hardware issue, it's nearly impossible to diagnose it in detail without access to the hardware. PS: Which Mac model is this?

Comment: ok i will try that. Thank you for your reply. It is a macbook air 2017 model.